# Showing a Toast notification from a service

Tags: android, android-service, android-notifications, android-alertdialog, toast

I have a background service that monitors foreground apps. It's used to protect a certain app such that if the protected app is in the foreground and then pushed to the background because another app started, it would show the user a notification that another app has taken over as the foreground app.

I'm able to detect the switch, but is there any way to display a Toast notification/AlertDialog to alert the user in the service after detection?

Comment: It's bad idea to display Alert Dialog in Service. You need activity context for showing that. so navigate to activity from service and display alert dialog

Comment: OK, if I don't go the AlertDialog way, how about Toast, or some other form of notification? Note that the Activity that takes over the foreground app doesn't belong to me. It may have hijacked my Actitivy

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get the app base context in `Service` class and show a toast using a `Handler`.

```
private Context appContext;

@Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        appContext = getBaseContext();        //Get the context here
    }

    //Use this method to show toast
    void showToast(){
        if(null != appContext){
        Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() 
            {
               Toast.makeText(appContext, "Printing Toast Message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        });

        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried this? I dont think it will work

Comment: I have used this in last project. And it works :)

Comment: What about dialogs?

Comment: As per his question/requirement Toast OR Dialog. This works for Toast. I have not tried for Dialogues

Comment: Thanks. This works perfectly for Toast. I don't actually need the AlertDialog, just needed a way of informing the user. Toast works just fine for now. Thanks again!

Comment: cheers! Happy Coding

Comment: Not working on android 10 error: ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy

Comment: How about snackbar?? I need a View to show a snackbar.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Handler to get main looper. Try below snipt

```
Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
handler.post(new Runnable(){
@Override
public void run(){
 Toast.makeText(YourServiceName.this,"your   message",Toast.LENGHT_SHORT).show();
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                 Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "TEST", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

               handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
                }
            },1000);
```